# Keep Java Program Window Open even if show button is used

Tags: java, windows, swing, window, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have a Java program where I want to keep the window open as we have in Window gadgets .

For example like if i want to keep window always on top I can following with the Jframe

`frame.setAlwaysOnTop( true );`

But if i use show desktop button i.e. the button in the bottom right corner of windows 7 , my Java Windows is also minimised . But Windows gadgets like clock etc are not minimised .

Do we have a way in Java to keep Java window open even if show desktop button is clicked ?